# Disable Chrome mobile's "tap to search" on a web app

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, mobile-chrome

I would like to be able to disable, through JavaScript or some sort of HTML meta-tag, the **tap-to-search/touch-to-search** feature found on **mobile Chrome** which shows a banner at the bottom of the browser every time the user long presses/taps on a word in any text paragraph.

This Chrome feature is a problem for me because this contextual banner completely covers the toolbar in the web app that I am developing, which is fixed at the bottom of the page.

I've only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648401/disable-mobile-chrome-43s-touch-to-search-feature-programmatically) question from 2015 which references [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/tap-to-search) Google Developers article (also from 2015), but the proposed solutions do not seem to work anymore except CSS "user-select: none"; unfortunately, disabling user selection is not a solution for me since user selection is required for my web app to work.

I have also tried setting event.preventDefault() when the "oncontextmenu" event fires, which does disable the search toolbar when the user *taps* on a word, but not when a user *long presses* on a word, as far as I have experienced.

So far the only partial "solution" that has worked for me has been to install the web app: as an installed PWA, tap-to-search does not somehow trigger. It still annoys me a lot that I would have to basically beg my potential users to install the web app on mobile.

I also know that the user can *manually* disable this feature globally in the Chrome Flags, but this is, I imagine, really annoying for a potential user as well.

Is there anything I am missing here? Do you know of any way to prevent tap-to-search from firing on a long press?

Comment: I bookmarked your question because I have the same requirement and if I find an answer I'll come back and let you know.

Comment: @BillyBackBedroom thanks a lot! I haven't found a solution yet...fingers crossed.

Comment: I did discover that if you use `contenteditable=true` and `inputmode=none` on an element, you don't get a keyboard but you do get selectable text and no Google snoopy search box. With the right event traps it you might be able to get a contenteditable to act readonly...

Answer (score 9):

Adding the attribute `tabindex="-1"` to the `<body>` tag works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, it isn't possible to disable touch-to-search (when this is triggered by a long-press for text selection) in chrome mobile. The Google Developers article is apparently concerned only with touch-to-search triggered through a tap gesture.

Quoting donnd, from [bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=949698&q=touch-to-search&can=2):

> Regarding #2 -- developer control: The 2015 article that you mentioned (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/tap-to-search) focuses on triggering through the tap gesture. As you correctly point out, it does not address the long-press gesture triggering. Touch to Search responds to both tap and long-press but treats them differently. As I'm sure you know, the long-press gesture activates a whole set of features which can include copy, translation, smart text selection, and Web Search. A site developer can markup their page text as non-selectable in order to disable the long-press gesture entirely, but currently there's no way to disable only the Touch to Search response to long pressing. If you'd like to work with us to add such a feature, let us know and we'll file a separate feature request.