# How do I stop Brave browser on Android turning static text into web links?

Tags: android, html, brave

While testing my web page on Brave browser on Android, there was an unexpected behaviour where a person's name that was displayed in the page within a td element was automatically turned into a web search link, e.g.

```
<td>James Cameron</td>
```

The test name happened to be 'James Cameron' (no relation) and presumably the browser has automatically Googled the text content and provided a link to the film producer of the same name in a panel at the bottom of the page.  I don't want this, as it's intrusive and inappropriate for my use case.  Is there a way to prevent this behaviour, perhaps by adding a META tag?
I don't get this happening with Safari on IOS.

[image: Screenshot showing problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature of Android is apparently called 'Touch to Search', and it can be switched off in Settings.

[Touch to Search dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh223.png)

[Touch to Search settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We3mM.png)

It's not specific to the Brave browser, and there doesn't appear to be an official way to disable this although there is a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64619907/13117403

My question is a duplicate of [Disable Chrome mobile's "tap to search" on a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640608/disable-chrome-mobiles-tap-to-search-on-a-web-app)